# Should every single action need a component in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular,

I have successfully coded a login system using JWT ( Backend is PHP / Lumen ).

When I login, I store the user info in the local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({email, token: res.token}));
```

So, basically, logout is just removing this file, one line of code.

Is it necessary to create a whole component for logout action ?

It seems a lot for me.

Can you a propose me a easier way to do it ? I don't really know how should I organise it.

Comment: Is that logout button in your navbar?

Comment: No, you can do it however you want. For example one would want to create a component because for code separation and perform some other stuff before logout happens. Depends on your logic upon logging out

Comment: @yer yes it is, in a dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal opinion is that you must use some kind of service for this case, so that you can inject it in whatever component you need it.

The service can be something like that

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor() {}

  logout() {
      this.cookies.delete() // this line is pseudo code
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

You might call it like that

```html
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./some-service path";

@Component({
  selector: "app-recursive",
  templateUrl: "./recursive.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./recursive.component.css"]
})
export class RecursiveComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  nextLayer = [];

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  logoutFunc() {
    this.auth.logout(); // If we asume that you have logout method in the service
  }

}
```

Here you can dive deeper in the logic behind the services [TourOfHeroesServicesChapter](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) , also i advice you to go trough each part of the tour of heroes, there is a lot of useful stuff

Comment: yes, I have it this way for the login. But how should I call it ?

Comment: I already have it written in AuthService: I should call it this way this.authenticationService.logout();  but how should I trigger it ?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or codesandbox with a demo, or share the service.

Comment: yes, but how should I call logoutFunc() ? Yes, I know, I will read it but I like beginning with practice... I fall asleep with so much to read :)

Comment: or what should I put in the HTML ?

Comment: you can call the function on click in html like this (click)="logoutFunc()"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to necessarily have component for every action. Since your logout is in the navbar, you can write and perform all necesary actions in the navbar component to keep it organised